# Creating a common spring boot project with auto generated code

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, automation, code-reuse

I wish to create a template project which will consist of spring-boot-starter, starter-web, starter-data-jpa, starter-aop and would generate some common configuration code to be reused for a bunch of different projects sharing this benchmark project. For example, the configuration to create data source, tx manager, vendor adapter, common exception handling, AOP based logging should automatically be generated. The eventual idea is to use this project as a dependency and to create a baseline project through this dependency which will also generate packages and automate the package naming as per given standards along with the above mentioned automated code generation. Any idea or heads-up for this?

Comment: Please check https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/

Comment: Checkout the spring initalizr https://start.spring.io/ and here https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good use case for creating a [maven archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html) if that's your build system of choice. If not, Gradle doesn't seem to have an analog of that concept.

I've never tried to setup a template as a *dependency* so I'm not sure how well that would work out, but what I've done in the past is just setup a git repo that has all of the boilerplate code like you're talking about, and then cloning and adapting to the specific project. The added benefit to this is that I can update the template (like for bug fixes) independently of the projects that use it, merge in those changes, test for breaking changes, and redeploy.

You may also be interested in [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech/), which is a project generator with lots more bells and whistles (I'm not associated). I haven't used it that much, but the project has a huge following.

Answer (score 1):

In order to complete [drognisep's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1965524/drognisep), you can find a full example of Spring boot custom maven archetype [here](https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-a-custom-maven-archetype-to-generate) (Which I think the best solution for your problem).

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! However, most of the java projects are running in Gradle hence even if I develop a custom archetype what are the realistic chances that it can be migrated to Gradle build system?

Comment: Good catch, in order to generate a Gradle based project from an exiting Maven archetype, you can use this plugin:  https://github.com/orctom/gradle-archetype-plugin 

However, if I were in your place, I would re-implement the Maven archetype in Gradle ecology by using templates:  https://github.com/townsfolk/gradle-templates/wiki/Template-Customization

Comment: Got your point! Going by the reference examples, what I understood is I need to have a baseline project consisting of runnable testable source code, and I need to copy these source code to the target locations in the archetype/template generating project while replacing the package name and project name with required placeholders wherever applicable. Can you suggest me any alternative to automate this manual process of copying the source code from one location to another while replacing this package names with placeholders at the same time?

Comment: An archetype in maven or template in gradle defines an original pattern or model from which all other things of the same kind are made. It provides a great way to enable developers quickly in a way consistent with best practices employed by your project or organization.